# Why does opening SDE Workspace Factory ask for credentials again? ArcObjects C#

Tags: arcobjects, c#, enterprise-geodatabase, workspace

I'm trying to open SDE Workspace Factory using [IWorkspaceFactory.Open](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#IWorkspaceFactory_Open.htm)

I give the complete Property set in the code to open.

```
ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.IPropertySet propertySet = new ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.PropertySetClass();
propertySet.SetProperty("SERVER", "myServer");
propertySet.SetProperty("INSTANCE", "myinstance");
propertySet.SetProperty("AUTHENTICATION_MODE", "DBMS");
propertySet.SetProperty("DATABASE", "myDatabase");
propertySet.SetProperty("USER", "sde");
propertySet.SetProperty("PASSWORD", "sdePassword");
propertySet.SetProperty("VERSION", "sde.DEFAUALT");
            

IWorkspaceFactory workspaceFactory = new ESRI.ArcGIS.DataSourcesGDB.SdeWorkspaceFactory();
IWorkspace workspace = workspaceFactory.Open(propertySet,0);
```

But When the `workspaceFactory.Open` is called, a dialogue box is opened to ask for credentials again.

[image: Connection Properties]

Why does this happen?

Also, Can someone tell me what does the second parameter of [IWorkspaceFactory.Open](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#IWorkspaceFactory_Open.htm) "hWnd" represent? I couldnt find a proper explanation in the documentation.

Comment: There aren't many reasons to *ever* hard-code the `sde` user password into an application. In fact, there aren't many reasons to ever connect as the `sde` user, period.

Comment: You have a typo in the default version name.

Comment: The hWnd argument is usually 0, it's the applications' hWnd https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//00230000003n000000 just in case you have implemented a custom connection dialog the IWorkspaceFactory.Open can find the application to create a proper child window... I have *never* used any value other than 0 for this argument.